# Can we access AWS Quantum DB (QLDB) database from a .NET application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

I am new to AWS Quantum DB (QLDB).

I am developing a .NET application that needs to connect to the database that offers immutablity. We came across QLDB that fulfils this requirement.

Is it possible to connect to QLDB from a .NET application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Getting started with the Amazon QLDB driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-driver.html):

> These drivers
> similarly encapsulate logic that converts a standard set of commands
> and functions into specific calls that are required by the service's
> low-level API.
>
> The driver is open-sourced on GitHub and is available for the
> following programming languages:
>
> - Java driver
> - .NET driver
> - Go driver
> - Node.js driver
> - Python driver